# Why do I get ORA-01013 error when executing batch with HQL when the query takes less than a second to execute

Tags: oracle

Am getting below error for an HQL query. Have set the statement timeout to -1 as well as 0 in weblogic console but still same error. The query printed in logs takes 0.856 seconds to execute on oracle SQL developer and fetches 3986 rows.

Query:

```
 select kpiResultDO
   from KPIResult  kpiResultDO
  where kpiResultDO.processedFl = 'NO'
    and kpiResultDO.typeCd in ('ABC','XYZ', 'PQR')
  order by kpiResultDO.seq
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
```

Comment: please show a [mcve] thanks

Comment: can you please send us the explain plan of the query, as it would give more information on what is happening in the Oracle DB.

Comment: am just retrieving data from the DB its a reader query for batch.